# Relocating JENKINS_HOME on Windows when installed as service

Tags: windows, jenkins

To free up space on `C:`, I would like to move my Jenkins data files (specifically the `\jobs` directory) from the default installation directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` to `F:\Jenkins\home`. I *think* what I need to do is set the `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable to `F:\Jenkins\home`. But no matter what I try, the `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable is always set to the location of `jenkins.exe`.

Related:

- [How to change Jenkins default folder on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689139/how-to-change-jenkins-default-folder-on-windows)
- JIRA issue [JENKINS-13530 JENKINS_HOME ignored on Bundled Windows EXE](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13530) was closed as "not an issue"

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. [Moved jenkins data](http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2014/02/25/jenkins-home-win/) to F:\Jenkins\home
2. Stop the running jenkins service
3. Uninstall the jenkins service with `jenkins.exe uninstall`
4. Uninstall jenkins
5. Delete `%HOMEPATH%\.jenkins` directory
6. Delete old jenkins install directory
7. Download latest MSI installer `v1.597`
8. Installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins2` (renamed to ensure there are no stale values in the registry or config files)
9. Set system-level environment variable `JENKINS_HOME` to `F:\Jenkins\home`
10. Set user-level environment variable `JENKINS_HOME` to `F:\Jenkins\home`
11. [Modified `jenkins.xml`](http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2014/02/25/jenkins-home-win/) to use `<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="F:\Jenkins\home"/>`
12. Started the Jenkins service

At this point, when I look at the system configuration, `JENKINS_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins2`. So it seems it *must always* be set to the location of `jenkins.exe`.

Maybe I've answered my own question. I'd like to have the program and data separate, if possible. Do I have to install jenkins to my `F:\` drive? Or, is there a way to simply split off the `jobs` directory and leave everything else on `C:`?

Thanks!

**EDIT** : I did *not* have to move `JENKINS_HOME`, but instead was able to configure the *workspace* and *builds* directories, which moved all the heavy disk usage over to `F:`. The settings I chose were:

Workspace Root Directory = `F:/Jenkins/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`
Build Record Root Directory = `F:/Jenkins/jobs/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}/builds`

I manually migrated these directories so they would not have to be recreated. During this process I did lose my build history, but I'm okay with that for now.

Comment: Instead of relocating it, you could just use a symbolic link

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Pre Jenkins 2.121**

JENKINS_HOME is where Jenkins is installed which is not what you want to change. After you start up Jenkins, go to:

1. Manage Jenkins
2. System Configuration
3. Click the first "advanced" button

This gives you text fields where you can change the directory for the workspace and builds directories. Those are the two directories that use a good bit of disk space. Note that it will not move history. If you want to move the existing workspaces/etc, you'll need to manually copy them over.

**Post 2.121**
You have to set properties (not through the UI). The system property to use is jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir.

https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.121/#ui-option-for-custom-builds-and-workspace-directories-on-the-master-has-been-removed
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

Comment: Ah.. now *that* is a sneaky little button. Thanks! I'll try this out.

Comment: @AhmadArslan - which step can't you find?

Comment: I dont have advanced button

Comment: It's all the way on the right side of the screen. You might need to scroll right. I see it in both Jenkins 1 and 2.

Comment: the "advanced" button has been removed: https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.121/#ui-option-for-custom-builds-and-workspace-directories-on-the-master-has-been-removed

Comment: @Vortilion it is jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir. The list of system properties was linked from the announcements. I've updated my answer to include it directly.

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility is to move the entire contents of $JENKINS_HOME.

It does not require editing configuration files, and it preserves the build history.

1. Stop the running service: `jenkins.exe stop`
2. Uninstall the service: `jenkins.exe uninstall`
3. Copy C:\Jenkins\home to F:\Jenkins\home
4. Rename C:\Jenkins to something else, keep it as backup.
5. Go to F:\Jenkins\home
6. Reinstall the service: `jenkins.exe install`
7. Start Jenkins: `jenkins.exe start`

Enjoy the new disk space!

Comment: Nice approach! This was easy to follow and worked for me.

Comment: does it really work without changing the jenkins.xml?

Comment: @SKLTFZ I can't reproduce it now, but it memory serves it updates jenkins.xml with the new location.

Answer (score 16):

**For WINDOWS:**

Copy all data from
`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins` 
to `D:\Jenkins\home`

Go to Jenkins installed folder `C:\Program Files\Jenkins`

- **Stop** the running Jenkins service from the command line - `jenkins.exe stop`
- **Uninstall** the Jenkins service from the command line - `jenkins.exe uninstall`
- **Update** `jenkins.xml` as `<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="D:\JenkinsHome"/>`
- **Install** the Jenkins service from the command line- `jenkins.exe install`
- **Start** the Jenkins service from the command line- `jenkins.exe start`
- **Login** to Jenkins `http://localhost:8080`
- Navigate to `Manage Jenkins > Configure System`

**Verify Home directory must point to D:\JenkinsHome**

Comment: why do you have to stop the service from command line when you are going to uninstall  Jenkins? It is pointless as the service will start running the moment you install back Jenkins

Comment: Bty Uninstall Jenkins is mandatory ?? Can't do without that ?

Comment: it didn't work for me without the uninstall.

Comment: Finally! My question is how can you change the JENKINS_HOME value to be read from the system variables, instead of the hard coded value in the jenkins.xml?

Comment: @Fluch comment it: `<!--env name=... value=... -->`

Answer (score 7):

For Jenkins 2.0, it was only necessary to add a system environment variable called "JENKINS_HOME" that points to the new location. The steps I used:

1. Stop the container hosting Jenkins (e.g. Tomcat).
2. Add a system environment variable called "JENKINS_HOME" that points to the new location.
3. Restart the container hosting Jenkins.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jenkins version older than 2.0 than you should do following:

1) open jenkins -> manage Jenkins -> Configure System. Check the path of your Home Directory.
2) Stop the jenkins service.
3) copy the jenkins home directory to other drive or location you want to move.
4) open jenkins.xml from program files and modify the value `<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="d:\Jenkins"/>` Change the d:\Jenkins to your new path.
5) restart the Jenkins service.
6) test your job :)

Answer (score 4):

first set the jenkins home path and then run /install jenkins.war

example :

```
set JENKINS_HOME=D:\
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8091 -path=D:\<some-folder-name>\
```

Comment: When using the jenkins.war file, this is the answer that works!

Answer (score 4):

Having the same problem and not wanting to change the whole `%JENKINS_HOME%` location, I came across the [answer by adil ameen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51394813/4747042)

Modify the `config.xml` file in `%JENKINS_HOME%` (typical under C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins).
Change `<workspaceDir>` and `<buildsDir>` to your desired folder.

You can use the following placeholders: `${JENKINS_HOME}`, `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}`, `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`. As specified at [Features controlled by system properties](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) under `jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir`

Mine looks like this:

```
  <workspaceDir>D:/jenkins/jobs/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}/workspace</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>D:/jenkins/jobs/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}/builds</buildsDir>
```

Reload the configuration through the Jenkins UI via `Jenkins` -> `Manage Jenkins` -> `Reload configuration from disk`

You can even keep your build history if you copy the old jobs to the new location.

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this question because I was short on HDD on C:/ but had plenty on D:/.

[The answer of Jeanne Boyarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035838/520162) had exactly zero effect on my Jenkins. Although I changed the two variables, Jenkins still used the original `workspace` and `jobs` directories which consumed 1/3 of my C:/ drive.

A colleague pointed me to the dead easy solution of simply using **Symbolic Links** for the directories.

After shutting down Jenkins, open your `CMD` on the `%JENKINS_HOME%` directory and simply create two links for the big directories:

```
pushd %JENKINS_HOME%
:: save the old directories
ren workspace workspace.old
ren jobs jobs.old
:: now create the links
mklink /D /J workspace D:\jenkins\workspace
mklink /D /J jobs D:\jenkins\jobs
:: copy the original jobs to the new location
xcopy jobs.old\* jobs\ /sy
```

After this, restart your Jenkins. If everything works fine, you can safely delete the `.old` directories.

Comment: This is a good way to do it; it gets the builds out of the default (and inappropriate) location in %Program Files (x86)%, while keeping the Jenkins blissfully unaware of the change.