# How to change workspace and build record Root Directory on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, workspace

I would like Jenkins' data to be written to drive "E:" since this is the large drive on the server. Jenkins itself is installed on "C:".

How do I do that?

The default configuration that I saw is:

> **Workspace Root Directory:** ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace
>   **Build Record Root Directory:** ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds

Will the following changes help me achieve what I need?

> **Workspace Root Directory:** E:/Jenkins/workspace
>   **Build Record Root Directory:** E:/Jenkins/builds/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}

In addition, what does "${ITEM_FULL_NAME}" mean?

Answer (score 45):

I figured it out.
In order to save your Jenkins data on other drive you'll need to do the following:

**Workspace Root Directory:** E:\Jenkins\${ITEM_FULL_NAME}\workspace
**Build Record Root Directory:** E:\Jenkins\${ITEM_FULL_NAME}\builds

[image: Change Directory]

Comment: What happened to **ITEM_ROOTDIR**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the Jenkins help explains the difference between `ITEM_ROOTDIR` and `ITEM_FULL_NAME`. See my answer.

Comment: looks like this option is gone from jenkins UI, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/51394813/1194180 instead

Answer (score 43):

You can modify the path on the `config.xml` file in the default directory

```
<projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
<workspaceDir>D:/Workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
<buildsDir>D:/Logs/${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/Build</buildsDir>
```

Comment: see ${JENKINS_HOME}/config.xml and change <workspaceDir> accordingly, save, and then reload configuration from disk via UI. you can check the results in the systeminfo UI

Comment: where is that config.xml

Comment: @EugenSunic in /var/lib/jenkins/ directory.

Answer (score 31):

**EDIT: Per other comments, the "Advanced..." button appears to have been removed in more recent versions of Jenkins. If your version doesn't have it, see [knorx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51989018/5003971).**

I had the same problem, and even after finding [this old pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/182) I still had trouble finding where to specify the Workspace Root Directory or Build Record Root Directory at the system level, versus specifying a custom workspace for each job.

To set these:

1. Navigate to `Jenkins` -> `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure System`
2. Right at the top, under `Home directory`, click the `Advanced...` button:
   [image: advanced button under Home directory]
3. Now the fields for Workspace Root Directory and Build Record Root Directory appear:
   [image: additional directory options]
4. The information that appears if you click the help bubbles to the left of each option is very instructive. In particular (from the Workspace Root Directory help):

   > This value may include the following variables:
   >
   > - `${JENKINS_HOME}` — Absolute path of the Jenkins home directory
   > - `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}` — Absolute path of the directory where Jenkins stores the configuration and related metadata for a given job
   > - `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` — The full name of a given job, which may be slash-separated, e.g. foo/bar for the job bar in folder foo
   >
   > The value should normally include `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}` or `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`, otherwise different jobs will end up sharing the same workspace.

Comment: For me Jenkins ignores the change in workspace root directory, even after restarting the slave

Comment: @Rolle did you get around this?

Comment: Looks like they removed the Advanced button at some point.  See @adil ameen's answer to change this in the config.xml file directly.

Comment: the button has been removed and explained in here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.121/#ui-option-for-custom-builds-and-workspace-directories-on-the-master-has-been-removed

Answer (score 20):

The variables you need are explained here in the jenkins wiki: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

The default variable ITEM_ROOTDIR points to a directory inside the jenkins installation. As you already found out you need:

- Workspace Root Directory:
  E:/myJenkinsRootFolderOnE/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}/workspace
- Build Record Root Directory: E:/myJenkinsRootFolderOnE/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}/builds

You need to achieve this through config.xml nowadays. Citing from the wiki page linked above:

> This used to be a UI setting, but was removed in 2.119 as it did not
> support migration of existing build records and could lead to
> build-related errors until restart.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest editing the /etc/default/jenkins

```
vi /etc/default/jenkins
```

And changing the $JENKINS_HOME variable (around line 23) to

```
JENKINS_HOME=/home/jenkins
```

Then restart the Jenkins with usual

```
/etc/init.d/jenkins start
```

Cheers!

Comment: Your suggestion is just wrong. `${JENKINS_HOME}` contains ALL Jenkins data; system configs, jobs, logs, etc. OP only asked about moving [${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds - jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-buildsdir) and [${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME} - jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-workspacedirname), both of which are no longer accessible via the UI. It also no longer uses init.d, instead, systemd

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the config.xml file in your JENKINS_HOME directory.
Use c32hedge's response as a reference and set the workspace location to whatever you want between the  tags

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jenkins stores all of its data in this directory on the file system.

There are a few ways to change the Jenkins home directory:

- Edit the `JENKINS_HOME` variable in your Jenkins configuration file (e.g. `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` on Red Hat Linux).
- Use your web container's admin tool to set the `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable.
- Set the environment variable `JENKINS_HOME` before launching your web container, or before launching Jenkins directly from the WAR file.
- Set the `JENKINS_HOME` Java system property when launching your web container, or when launching Jenkins directly from the WAR file.
- Modify `web.xml` in jenkins.war (or its expanded image in your web container). This is not recommended.
  This value cannot be changed while Jenkins is running. 
  It is shown here to help you ensure that your configuration is taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Configure under Home there is a "Help" note on how to:

Home directory  /var/lib/jenkins    Help for feature: Home directory

By default, Jenkins stores all of its data in this directory on the file system.

There are a few ways to change the Jenkins home directory:

```
Edit the JENKINS_HOME variable in your Jenkins configuration file (e.g. /etc/sysconfig/jenkins on Red Hat Linux).
Use your web container's admin tool to set the JENKINS_HOME environment variable.
Set the environment variable JENKINS_HOME before launching your web container, or before launching Jenkins directly from the WAR file.
Set the JENKINS_HOME Java system property when launching your web container, or when launching Jenkins directly from the WAR file.
Modify web.xml in jenkins.war (or its expanded image in your web container). This is not recommended.
```

This value cannot be changed while Jenkins is running.
It is shown here to help you ensure that your configuration is taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Jenkins versions provide the System Properties  `jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir` and `jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir` for this purpose, see [Jenkins Features Controlled with System Properties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-buildsdir) (which also explains the placeholders `${JENKINS_HOME}`, `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}`, `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`, `${ITEM_FULLNAME}`)

I'm not familiar with Windows but I wrote [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77279767/3301051) on how to set them on an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score -1):

```
def finder = new FileNameFinder()
def files = finder.getFileNames '\\pkg\\stage\\', '*.sln'
echo "$files"
```

jenkins is serching file in /var/lib/jenkins/pkg/stage
it is automatically adding /var/lib/jenkins path before