# Angular 4 Assets not copying when creating build using Jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins

I am creating build of angular 4 project using Jenkins and then publishing build on ftp.

Following is command that i am running

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

I have created dev as following in package.json.

```
"dev": "ng build"
```

When jenkins build run, build is created and uploaded on the ftp. All the content is uploaded on the ftp except the content which is in angular-cli.json assets

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    ".htaccess"
  ],
```

Assets, favicon and htaccess files are not getting uploaded on the ftp.

Comment: I checked folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\DEVHMS\dist, in this folder assets folder is not  created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.
Issue was with folder name (Program Files (x86)). 
Installed jenkins to another directory(programs) and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can also just change the workspace directory in `Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System` (click advanced)

I set mine to `c:\workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`

(ref: [How to change workspace and build record Root Directory on Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854377/how-to-change-workspace-and-build-record-root-directory-on-jenkins))