# Jenkins workspace settings issues in Windows

Tags: jenkins

I have the latest stable release of Jenkins 2.121.1 installed on my Windows10Pro(x64)-build machine.

**Problem no 1:**

I can't find the system-wide workspace settings as shown for instance in this thread:
[How to change workspace and build record Root Directory on Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854377/how-to-change-workspace-and-build-record-root-directory-on-jenkins)

Has this been removed? I only have the workspace settings available for the specific jobs, but I would like to change it on a system-wide-level.

**Problem no 2:**

When I configure the custom work space for a specific job like so:
[image: custom work space]

It is supposed to use the name for the item that I've created. Instead it LITERALLY creates a folder with this name, like so:
[image: literally]

Even though the jenkins documentation says I should use "${ITEM_FULL_NAME}", I've tried different variants (ITEM_FULLNAME) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug

[image]

They mention Under the Advance Tab but I don't find it anywhere either.

**Workaround**

Modify the jenkins.xml directly 
from

```
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
```

to

```
<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="newPath\Jenkins"/>
```

Considering the 2nd issue you can modify the config.xml

[image]

Or

You can set the env variable when you start the jenkins.war

```
 SET JENKINS_HOME=new\Path\directory
 SET ITEM_ROOTDIR=new\root\directory

 java -jar jenkins.war
```

You will have to do this each time you start and stop the services

Comment: That did it! I did not have access (even as administrator) to change the config.xml-file, but after changing the access properties (by right-clicking & properties) I was able to change the file. Thanks!