# How to find Advanced options in Jenkins Configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to change the default location of my workspace in Jenkins, however when I go to Jenkins - Manage Jenkins ->Configure System I don't see a button for "Advanced..." that seems to be the right place to do such change.

[image]

I've got Jenkins 2.129 and I'm logged in as admin user with full permissions. Am I missing some plugins?

Comment: it's a bug .... look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127071/jenkins-workspace-settings-issues-in-windows/51128788#51128788

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it in the config.xml file:

```
  <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}</workspaceDir>
```

You have a full example in this github repository:
https://github.com/CloudStack-extras/jenkins-config/blob/master/config.xml