# Where to find option to change workspace path location in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have recently installed Jenkin autodeploy tool. But I want to change it's default workspace location path which is pointing to my installable directory(c:) but now I want to keep my all projects in other drive so for that need to change workspace location.

But in my jenkin portal I am not finding that option.

Can anyone suggest me where can I find that?

Please see screen shot as well.
[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCGk8.jpg)

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: **duplicate** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854377/how-to-change-workspace-and-build-record-root-directory-on-jenkins

Comment: @JRichardsz I am not finding that advance button under home directory?

Comment: @Vijay what is your jenkins version?

Comment: @JRichardsz  it is jenkins-2.121.2 windows version

Comment: @JRichardsz I have tried to use jenkins-2.134 as well but there is no effect. In this version as well I am not seeing advance tab under Jenkin Home Directory text field.

Answer (score 6):

This option was [removed](https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.121/#ui-option-for-custom-builds-and-workspace-directories-on-the-master-has-been-removed) in 2.121:

> Build Record Root Directory and Workspace Root Directory can no longer be configured through the UI as these options were generally unsafe to use while Jenkins was running. Instead, these locations can now be customized using system properties on startup. Existing changes to these options will be retained unless and until overridden at startup.

Further details under [JENKINS-50164](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50164).

Under the new model, one sets the workspace root with the `hudson.model.Slave.workspaceRoot` system property, which can be set as follows:

```
-Dhudson.model.Slave.workspaceRoot=/whatever
```

The exact mechanism for setting a property like this varies by OS/platform, but many typical options are described [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins-). The [full list of available system](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) properties is on the Jenkins Wiki.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide some additional detail/links.

Answer (score 5):

Since I also couldn't find under **Jenkins** -> **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** the Advanced option. Where you can add a different directory for **Build Record Root Directory**. 
You can change this property directly in the **config.xml** in the root folder of your Jenkins.

[image]

Here you can update the property to what you need to.

I would recommend using the following structure,

**/path_to_the_folder/${ITEM_FULLNAME}/builds**

Because using **${ITEM_FULLNAME}** in the path, will put the builds of every job into its own folder.