# Jenkins CI build issue

Tags: jenkins

On compiling Jenkins CI build the module lint got failed and throws below exception,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  null value in entry: outputDirectory=null
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: outputDirectory=null
  at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:33)
  at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.entryOf(ImmutableMap.java:135)
  at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.put(ImmutableMap.java:206)
  at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap$Builder.put(ImmutableSortedMap.java:371)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$LazyTaskExecution.getOutputFilesSnapshot(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:327)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.OutputFilesTaskStateChanges.getPrevious(OutputFilesTaskStateChanges.java:39)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.iterator(AbstractNamedFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:98)

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Exception clearly points the error: `outputDirectory=null` which should not be null

Comment: yes but not sure the exact issue do I need to change anything in configuration ? same was working yeterday today it's failed

Comment: Not an expert on Jenkins setup but you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34854377/2987755

Comment: ok let me check Thank you :)

Comment: This issue has been resolved by deleting gradle file in CI job location :)

Comment: good, thanks for the update :)