# Difference between jenkins workspace and my base code location

Tags: jenkins

What is the difference between Jenkins workspace and my local checkout code.

When I am running my code from the command prompt, my build is getting successfully, same code when I am running via jenkins i am getting build error.

```
modules\ant\build.xml:366: Spaces not supported for installation location path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\
```

can you please someone clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `space` symbol in to the path to Jenkins workspace. Better move your workspaces in path like `C:\work\`. Or even you can move them to another disk. You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34918545/2908599) as reference how to change it.

Comment: Hi Romeo,  I have updated my workshop location in config.xml file and right now my work space is pointing C:drive and i am getting expected result. Thanks lot for the quick response.