# Jenkins startup error: jenkins.model.InvalidBuildsDir: does not contain ${ITEM_FULL_NAME} or ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}, cannot distinguish between projects

Tags: java, jenkins

Help please. In our workflow we only work with pre-packaged offline deploys where we do not have root access and therefore use supervisord to stop start ALL packages. We deploy all our packages under a user account. I have created a custom Jenkins package. Its basically its a folder containing the Jenkins war file and configurations from when I tool a vanilla initial setup.

My installation has worked up until now. Seems trying to get things running for the first time seems flaky. Once running Jenkins is fine. This time I am trying to deploy the packages (they have not changed) however I cannot start Jenkins and get and error:

*jenkins.model.InvalidBuildsDir: does not contain ${ITEM_FULL_NAME} or ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}, cannot distinguish between projects*

So what I did was get a clean fresh install running and packaged it up. Basically I untar the jenkins directory then use supervisord to control start/stop.

**Supervisord config:**

```
[program:jenkins]
autorestart = true
autostart = true
command = /bin/bash -c "set JENKINS_HOME=/opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jenkins; /opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jdk/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir=/opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins/builds/${ITEM_FULL_NAME} -Djenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir=/opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME} -jar /opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jenkins/bin/jenkins.war -path=/opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jenkins"
directory = /opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jenkins
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /opt/home/svc_user/opskit/log/jenkins.log
stdout_logfile_backups = 5
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stopwaitsecs = 300
```

**Full error:**

```
jenkins.model.InvalidBuildsDir: /opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins/builds does not contain ${ITEM_FULL_NAME} or ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}, cannot distinguish between projects
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.checkRawBuildsDir(Jenkins.java:3179)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setBuildsAndWorkspacesDir(Jenkins.java:3135)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3123)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3125)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1200(Jenkins.java:320)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$13.run(Jenkins.java:3219)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1133)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:50)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1166)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:966)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

**Jenkins config.xml:**

```
<workspaceDir>/opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
<buildsDir>/opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins/builds/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</buildsDir>
```

**Folder permissions (install dir):**

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 svc_user svc_user   39 Jun  4 02:51 jenkins -> /opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jenkins-2.222.3
drwxr-xr-x 13 svc_user svc_user 4096 May  1 05:07 jenkins-2.222.3
```

**Folder permissions (custom dir for builds and workspaces):**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 svc_user svc_user 37 Jun  4 02:51 jenkins -> /opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins-2.222.3
drwxr-xr-x 4 svc_user svc_user 37 Jun  4 16:39 jenkins-2.222.3

  |-nginx-1.16.1
  |-jdk-8u91
  |-jenkins-2.222.3
  |  |-builds
  |  |-workspace
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Modified this:**

```
command = /bin/bash -c "JENKINS_HOME=/opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jenkins /opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jdk/bin/java...
```

^^
Nothing to do with the fix, just launches 1 java process instead of 2.

**Deleted:**

```
-Djenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir=/opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins/builds/${ITEM_FULL_NAME} 

-Djenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir=/opt/home/svc_user/data/jenkins/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}
```

^^
Fixed my startup issue. Not sure why these had no negative effects on previous installations.

**Also deleted:**

```
path=/opt/home/svc_user/opskit/jenkins
```

Seemed isnt necessary.

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message when trying to set `.buildsDir` and `.workspacesDir` on an Ubuntu system.
Obviously I couldn't solve it by removing those lines (as proposed in the other answer) because I wanted to make use of them.
The trick was to do the correct escaping in the systemctl config!

The config editor can be started with `sudo systemctl edit --full jenkins.service`
The relevant part of the config looks like this (mind the double `\\` before the `$` ! ):

```
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true \
        -Djenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir=/mypath_builds/\\${ITEM_FULL_NAME}  \
        -Djenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir=/mypath_work/\\${ITEM_FULL_NAME}"
```

See [Jenkins Features Controlled with System Properties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-buildsdir) for a description of the System Properties and the supported placeholders like `${JENKINS_HOME}`, `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}`, `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`, `${ITEM_FULLNAME}`.