# Why does Jenkins change my workspace path?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, testng, workspace

i have installed Jenkins on Windows 10 and each time i try to execute a maven project or just try to execute `mvn clean test` (command line), Jenkins decides that my new workspace should be: `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\eclipse-workspace\` while my project is in `C:\Users\username\eclipse-workspace`.
Jenkins starts in the directory `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\projectName` and even if i run a `cd` command i will have this problem:

> The driver executable must exist:
> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\eclipse-workspace\projectname\drivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe

My chrome driver is not there obviously but it's in `C:\Users\userName\eclipse-workspace\projectName\drivers\chromedriver`.

It looks like than Jenkins changes my `user.home`.
I went to config file and set:

```
<workspaceDir>C:\Users\userName\eclipse-workspace</workspaceDir>
```

but it's still looking for the driver in `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\eclipse-workspace\projectname\drivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe`

This part: `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\` is obtained using in Java `System.getProperty("user.home")`. Running it with Jenkins seems to modify it.

Why is it looking for my driver there?
Why can't it just stick to my workspace folder?
How can i solve this?

Thank you

Comment: update: tried to set a path without variables in Java and it is still looking for the driver in C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\eclipse-workspace\projectname\drivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe

Comment: update2: i tried to change Path variable in Jenkins, didn't work. I also added user.home in Jenkin environment variables and changed USERPROFILE variable. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: Running Jenkins on Windows is a bad idea! Sorry, had to say it. It looks like you have to make some changes on local system `$PATH` and `Environment Variables` . Have you tried writing a `Hello world` directly in the path where it wants to build i.e., C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\eclipse-workspace\  . If it is working in its own preferred workspace, changing to that point may be an easier option. Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854377/how-to-change-workspace-and-build-record-root-directory-on-jenkins

Comment: Thank you  mdabdullah, Jenkins on Windows was not my choiche, i am in a corporate environment, so i guess i have to work with what i am given....honestly i would not like to change my workspace directory just because of Jenkins

Comment: tried to edit `config.xml`. It started a new installation, but it's still going for `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\eclipse-workspace\projectname\drivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe`.
i edited my Java class so that i do not use `user.home` variable, still not wrking
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\eclipse-workspace\\project\\drivers\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: If i use the `war` file it does not happen. It happens only when installing Jenkins as `windows service`

Comment: While I dont fully understand the problem, I do appreciate it I have only setup windows slaves and things were simpler. Setting up `master` on Windows may not be as simple. I recommend you align to jenkins because there are more hardcoded paths coming along the way like `slave path` , `environment variables` , `build logs` etc which appears to be a growing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i solved it. I was running under **Local System Account**
https://jenkins-le-guide-complet.github.io/html/sect-windows-service.html#fig-hudson-windows-service-config

I had edit the service as shown in the link.

Comment: this prevents chromedriver to display browser....goddamnit