# no configuration file provided: not found (docker-compose.yml) under the jenkins worksapce in Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose

Why is `docker compose up` cannot be executed under jenkins' workspace directory, saying `no configuration file provided: not found`:

```bash
# It doesn't work under the jenkins workspace
root@VM-0-7-ubuntu:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/minimal-react-app# ls
dist  docker  docker-compose.yml
root@VM-0-7-ubuntu:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/minimal-react-app# docker compose up -d
no configuration file provided: not found  # <----- why?
 
# However, it works under user's home directory
root@VM-0-7-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/minimal-react-app# ls
dist  docker  docker-compose.yml
root@VM-0-7-ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/minimal-react-app# docker compose up -d
[+] Running 7/7
 ✔ nginx 6 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled    
# ...
```

They are the same files but inside different folders, but one works and the other don't, why is this?

Comment: While the above is using `root` user, and change user to `jenkins` does not make any difference either...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by changing jenkins' workspace directory to another place, and finally managed to make it work. See [How to change workspace and build record Root Directory on Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51394813/16648127)

This is the result:

```bash
# before: it was the default path:
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace

# after: 
/home/jenkins_home/jenkins/workspace
```